# Can execute ping on Windows PC but not MacOS (where to implement ping-t)?

Tags: python, ping

I am helping out one of our programming teachers and cannot figure out this issue: His students were given this code to demonstrate how ping, trace route and nslookup work in Python. The code runs fine on Windows PCs but our students and teachers use MacBook Airs with an M1 chip. There must be something Syntax wise that isn't supported on MacOS. Any help is appreciated!
Here is the code:

````
#   p227_TR_possible_solution.py
#   Example Solution:
#     Will run in code editor but ping, tracert, and nslookup
#     commands will not execute
################################################################################
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tksc
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

#edits to this come from steps 9 and 10
def do_command(command):
    global command_textbox, url_entry

    # If url_entry is blank, use localhost IP address 
    url_val = url_entry.get()
    if (len(url_val) == 0):
        # url_val = "127.0.0.1"
        url_val = "::1"
    
    command_textbox.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    command_textbox.insert(tk.END, command + " working....\n")
    command_textbox.update()

    p = subprocess.Popen(command + ' ' + url_val, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    cmd_results, cmd_errors = p.communicate()
    command_textbox.insert(tk.END, cmd_results)
    command_textbox.insert(tk.END, cmd_errors)

#save comes from step 11
def mSave():
  filename = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.txt',filetypes = (('Text files', '*.txt'),('Python files', '*.py *.pyw'),('All files', '*.*')))
  if filename is None:
    return
  file = open (filename, mode = 'w')
  text_to_save = command_textbox.get("1.0", tk.END)
  
  file.write(text_to_save)
  file.close()

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

# set up button to run the do_command function
#Code to make the command button pass it's name to a function using lambda
#this portion will come from steps 8-10
ping_btn = tk.Button(frame, text="Check to see if a URL is up and active", command=lambda:do_command("ping"))
ping_btn.pack()

trace_btn = tk.Button(frame, text="Trace route to website", command=lambda:do_command("tracert"))
trace_btn.pack()

nslookup_btn = tk.Button(frame, text="Check the IP address of a website", command=lambda:do_command("nslookup"))
nslookup_btn.pack()

nslookup_btn = tk.Button(frame, text="Save", command=lambda:mSave())
nslookup_btn.pack()


#ping_btn.pack()

#create the frame with label for the text box
frame_URL = tk.Frame(root, pady=10,  bg="black") # change frame color
frame_URL.pack()

# decorative label, this comes from step 12
url_label = tk.Label(frame_URL, text="Enter a URL of interest: ", 
    compound="center",
    font=("comic sans", 14),
    bd=0, 
    relief=tk.FLAT, 
    cursor="heart",
    fg="mediumpurple3",
    bg="black")
url_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
url_entry= tk.Entry(frame_URL,  font=("comic sans", 14)) # change font
url_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)



frame = tk.Frame(root,  bg="black") # change frame color
frame.pack()

#this comes from step 6
command_textbox = tksc.ScrolledText(frame, height=10, width=100)
command_textbox.pack()


root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: For clarification, the assignment says to use the command "ping-t" for MacOS instead of the traditional "ping".

Comment: Too much code. Can you reduce this to a [mcve] please? Also be clearer on how this is not working. What happens when you run that code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? "ping-t" would probably be a typo, you need a space after `ping`. Just guessing though.